# Is the man in ibn Kathir's tafsir for Sura 114 being cured, or simply encouraged?

Tags: tafseer, prophet-muhammad, shaitan, health

Muhammad's response to the man(below) sounds very positive, but it is difficult to tell whether the man is being healed from his affliction, or just encouraged. Or perhaps could it be that Muhammad is just making a statement about Satan, as a warning, or to teach his followers?

Also, are we to understand that the man has a demon, or could he simply have OCD?

> (And so We have appointed for every Prophet enemies -- Shayatin among
>   mankind and Jinn, inspiring one another with adorned speech as a
>   delusion.) (6:112) Imam Ahmad recorded that Ibn 'Abbas said, "A man
>   came to the Prophet and said, 'O Messenger of Allah! Sometimes I say
>   things to myself that I would rather fall from the sky than say (aloud
>   openly). ' The Prophet said,
>
> (Allah is Most Great! Allah is Most Great! All praise is due to Allah
>   Who sent his (Shaytan's) plot back as only a whisper.)'' Abu Dawud and
>   An-Nasa'i also recorded this Hadith.

[Tafsir ibn Kathir, Sura 114](http://www.alim.org/library/quran/AlQuran-tafsir/TIK/114/1) -- At the bottom of the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The man is being reassured. The man came to the Prophet (ﷺ) seemingly worried that he is having those thoughts which he would never utter... and the Prophet's (ﷺ) response of praise of Allah (ﷻ) is letting him know that there's nothing to worry about as it is just a whisper [so long as he continues to do what he's doing i.e., not acting on the whispers].

Related hadith:

> Abu Hurairah said; His companion came to him and said; Messenger of Allah! We have thoughts which we cannot dare talk about and we do not like that we have them or talk about them. He said:
>   Have you experienced that? They replied: yes. He said : that is clear faith. [-Sunan Abi Dawud 5111](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/43/339).

It's not an issue of "being cured". Waswasa (whispers from Satan) is not a type of demonic possession, it's something that happens to everyone (e.g., the bad thoughts, tempting thoughts, etc). You don't have to have OCD to be having these thoughts. There's no cure because there's no end to Satan's attempts at mischief *until* the Day of Judgement.